# Bootstrap form text and input aligning in 2 columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm tryind to understand bootstrap v2.3.2.
I want to make form like this using divs...

[image]

I done this code with divs

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>

        <div class="row-fluid no-space">
            <div class="span3 blockkk">
                <p class="pull-right">1111111111111:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="span3 blockk ">
                <p class="pull-left">22222222</p>

            </div>
            <div class="span3 blockkk">
                <p class="pull-right">3333:</p></div>
            <div class="span3 blockk">
                <p class="pull-left">4444444444444</p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid no-space">
            <div class="span3 blockkk">
                <p class="pull-right">1111111111111:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="span3 blockk ">
                <p class="pull-left">22222222</p>

            </div>
            <div class="span3 blockkk">
                <p class="pull-right">3333:</p></div>
            <div class="span3 blockk">
                <p class="pull-left">4444444444444</p></div>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
</form>
```

it looks exactly as i need
[image]

Now i'm trying to ad there inputs and lables using divs 'control-group',
'control-label', 'controls' and it becomes hell :[ I dont understand how to place them there correctly(

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>

        <div class="row-fluid no-space">
            <div class="span6 ">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="span6 blockkk">
                             <div class="pull-right">
                                 <label class="control-label" for="textinput">Text Input</label>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="span6 blockk">
                            <div class="pull-left">
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder="placeholder" class="input-small" type="text">
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span6 blockk">
second row
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Tried this way but the code is huge, and i can't find the way to make this input move left... noway. 
[image]

How to solve this issue correctly? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap3 try the below :

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row" style="padding-bottom : 10px">
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-2">
            <label class="control-label pull-right">Text:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-2">
            <label class="control-label pull-right">Text:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="padding-bottom : 10px">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1">
            <label class="control-label pull-right">Text another one:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1">
            <label class="control-label pull-right">Text another one:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="padding-bottom : 10px">
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-2">
            <label class="control-label pull-right">And more:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-2">
            <label class="control-label pull-right">And more:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, but i need the solution for v2.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Using v2.3.2, try this - edit offset as required

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group row-fluid">
            <div class="span1 offset1">
                <label class="control-label pull-right" for="text">Text:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="controls span2" style="margin-left:80px">
                <input type="text" id="text">
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="span1 offset2">
                    <label class="control-label" for="text2">Text:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="controls span2" style="margin-left:80px">
                    <input type="text" id="text2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group row-fluid">
            <div class="span1 offset1">
                <label class="control-label pull-right" for="textAnother">Text another one:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="controls span2" style="margin-left:80px">
                <input type="text" id="textAnother">
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="span1 offset2">
                    <label class="control-label" for="textAnother2">Text another one:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="controls span2" style="margin-left:80px">
                    <input type="text" id="textAnother2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="control-group row-fluid">
            <div class="span1 offset1">
                <label class="control-label pull-right" for="andMore">And more:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="controls span2" style="margin-left:80px">
                <input type="text" id="andMore">
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="span1 offset2">
                    <label class="control-label" for="andMore2">And more:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="controls span2" style="margin-left:80px">
                    <input type="text" id="andMore2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```